# Different Browser Versions in the same Zalenium instance

Tags: zalenium

We are using Kubernetes zalenium.
Is there a way we can configure multiple browser versions in the same Zalenium instance?
So that i can run my tests in different versions of browsers

Answer (score 0):

Not really, we never developed that feature.